# Files I upload are not going into the right folder

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, upload

I thought I had my uploads working correctly on Friday, but when I tested the site this morning, it doesn't work right. My uploads are supposed to be going into an uploads/ file and then to a file that corresponds to the ProductID to which that upload is going.

Ex: My Test Product is ProductID 519. I want to upload a document so it should go to uploads/519. When I hover over the uploaded file, it says uploads/519/PhoneList.xls - which is correct. But when I check my Solution Explorer in Visual Studio 2010, the file shows up outside of the 519 file as 519PhoneList.xls

Can someone tell me why this is happening and help me figure out how to fix it? I've tried deleting a / here and there but I can't find the right place to fix.

```
 Protected Sub SubmitDocument_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles SubmitDocument.Click
    DocumentModal.Hide()
    'Builds the full absolute URL to be inserted into the database. 
    Dim hostURL As String = Request.Url.Scheme & "://" & Request.Url.Host & ":" & Request.Url.Port & Request.ApplicationPath
    Dim sqlFileHREF As String = Nothing
    Dim MarketingTitle As String = DocumentTitle.Text
    'SQL INSERT: Marketing Table
    sqlFileHREF = "INSERT INTO Marketing (ProductID, MarketingTypeID, MarketingTitle, MarketingData) VALUES (" & ProductID.Value & " ,4, '" & DocumentTitle.Text & "', '" & hostURL & "uploads/" & ProductID.Value & "/" & DocumentUpload.FileName & "')"
    sqlFileHREF.Replace("'", "''")
    DocumentUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/uploads/" & ProductID.Value & DocumentUpload.PostedFile.FileName))
    'Create SQL Connection
    Dim SqlConnection As New SqlConnection("Server=off-db1;uid=productsDB_admin;pwd=*****;database=Products")
    SqlConnection.Open()
    Dim sqlCommand As New SqlCommand(sqlFileHREF, SqlConnection)
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    SqlConnection.Close()
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)
End Sub 


<!-- Add a Document -->
    <li>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="DocumentButton" runat="server">Document</asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:Panel ID="DocumentPanel" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display:none">
            Title:<asp:TextBox ID="DocumentTitle" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:FileUpload ID="DocumentUpload" runat="server" />
            <asp:Label ID="DocumentLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Button ID="SubmitDocument" runat="server" Text="Upload" onclick="SubmitDocument_Click" /><asp:Button ID="CancelDocument" runat="server" Text="Cancel" /><asp:HiddenField ID="filename" runat="server" />
        </asp:Panel>       
        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="DocumentModal" runat="server" DropShadow="True" DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" PopupControlID="DocumentPanel" TargetControlID="DocumentButton"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
    </li>
```

Comment: The way you insert data is dangerous. You should read about SQL Injections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the folder 519 exists ?

DocumentUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/uploads/" & ProductID.Value & DocumentUpload.PostedFile.FileName))

That line has an error, you're missing a & "/" between productid.value and postedfile.filename.

Comment: Yep the folder exists. I added the & "/" & between the ProdudctID.Value and the DocumentUpload and it works. What a silly mistake, thanks for the extra pair of eyes! By the way, I have to wait 5 minutes to accept your answer.

Comment: @David: You should use code blocks when referencing code. It's much easier on the eyes.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
Server.MapPath("/uploads/" & ProductID.Value & "/" & DocumentUpload.PostedFile.FileName)
```

Might be easier using String.Format:

```
Server.MapPath(String.Format("/uploads/{0}/{1}", ProductId.Value, DocumentUpload.PostedFile.FileName))
```

Comment: Could you explain that for me? Is that just a different way of writing it?

Comment: Yea, it's just a different way of writing it. That way, you don't have to use ampersands to concatenate the string. Just more readable, in my humble opinion.

Comment: It is and it worked just as good as the first answer. I wish I was able to check both of the answers since they both work the same! Thanks!

Comment: @jlg: No worries. What matters is that you got it working. I'm assuming you upvoted, so thanks for that.

Comment: Yep that was me. Thanks for helping me with basically every question I have!